# Where to put Automapper maps in Nunit test assembly

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, automapper, fixtures

I am using Automapper in my application and I am testing the maps with fake objects, so I have slightly different maps in my tests than in my production code, what is the best way to create/call the maps, I have the maps sitting right now at each fixture's

```
[TestFixtureSetUp]
```

As the Mapper class is static is it possible to read the maps once per "all test" run, because I found it slows down the tests very much

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With NUnit you could use [`[SetUpFixture]`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setupFixture&r=2.4):

> This is the attribute that marks a class that contains the one-time
>   setup or teardown methods for all the test fixtures under a given
>   namespace. The class may contain at most one method marked with the
>   SetUpAttribute and one method marked with the TearDownAttribute.

With MbUnit you could use `[AssemblyFixture]` which is executed once per unit test assembly.

Comment: In NUnit 3 [Setup] needs to change to [OneTimeSetUp]